# Grant Execute Function permission to another user

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-grant, database-permissions

I have a database function `fn_relation_isModerator`, only user `api` has access to this function. Now I want another user to have this permission *(while keeping the previous permission as well)*.

I checked routine name and user by following query:

```
select routine_name, routine_type, definer from information_schema.ROUTINES where ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'db_name';
```

Which resulted:

```
+-------------------------+---------------+----------+
|      ROUTINE_NAME       |  ROUTINE_TYPE |  DEFINER |
+-------------------------+---------------+----------+
|                         |               |          |
| fn_relation_isModerator |  FUNCTION     |  api@%   |
+-------------------------+---------------+----------+
```

**Approach 1:**

So I ran the following query to grant this permission:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE db_name.fn_relation_isModerator TO 'api_worker'@'%';
```

But it resulted in following error:

> Error Code: 1305. PROCEDURE fn_relation_isModerator does not exist

**Approach 2:**

Query:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION `db_name`.`fn_relation_isModerator` TO 'api_worker'@'%';
```

Error

> Error Code: 1133. Can't find any matching row in the user table

**Approach 3:**

Query:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON `db_name`.`fn_relation_isModerator` TO 'api_worker'@'%';
```

Error:

> Error Code: 1144. Illegal GRANT/REVOKE command; please consult the
>   manual to see which privileges can be used

Comment: Are you trying to do it as root?

Comment: @MichaelO. Yes!

Comment: Your second approach is correct. Maybe try creating the user?

Comment: It already exists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use grant execute on the `function` (Approach 2):

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION `db_name`.`fn_relation_isModerator` TO 'api_workers'@'%';
```

As explained in the comments by OP, there was a typo in user, it should be `api_workers` instead of `api_worker`.

All approaches failed due to the use of non-existent user.

Comment: I already tried it, mentioned in **Approach 2**. Resulted with error `Error Code: 1133. Can't find any matching row in the user table`

Comment: Sorry I think I missed it. Then it means `api_worker` user on `%` host doesn't exist yet. Do a `SELECT CONCAT(User, '@', Host) FROM mysql.user;` to confirm.

Comment: Did you run that select query?

Comment: Which query? Sorry didn't get your reference?

Comment: No problem: `SELECT CONCAT(User, '@', Host) FROM mysql.user;`

Comment: Yes, here are the results https://image.ibb.co/cAx4v8/Screenshot_from_2018_06_10_01_59_00.png

Comment: You don't have `api_worker` user but `api_workers` (Watch `s`). Try with `'api_workers'@'%'`.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that and I can't explain how embarrassed I am. It worked with `api_workers`..

Comment: No problem. You could remove your question if you want as it was a simple typo.

Comment: I think we should improve your answer with this little detail, may be helpful for someone in the future.